# WPF Multiple Instances of Windows and MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

**How do I use multiple windows in an WPF MVVM app?**

I have a Main Window with a menu control that needs to open up new instances of the window each time the item it is selected. I need to be able to show windows next to each other, it is a requirement and not page or usercontrol navigation.

**Does anyone have an example of doing this?**

I've read it is not recommended UI design but it is the requirement I have to implement.

Comment: you need to open same window multiple times??

Comment: Create a new instance of your window each time .Try this`var p2 = new Presentation_2();
    p2.Show();`

Comment: Then discuss the requirement and find a better approach. Probably the person that created the requirement was not aware of the problems of this decission and the other options available and their benefits.

Comment: Yes I need to show multiple windows. I'm looking into Catel and also view the course for Prism multiple shells. I'm just not sure which one would mimic the current windows app. They have like 10 windows open at once. I am trying to get them to change their interface a little but they like have 4 the same windows next to each other.

Comment: There is a great course on pluralsight by one of the Prism owners, which shows how to create multiple shells. They have 30 days free trial.

Comment: I shouldn't have to change the requirements because the technology is lacking. Modals / Multiple windows for a high speed call center is normal interface so kudos to Caliburn!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have this working by using the WindowManager from Caliburn.Micro which seems like an very excellent framework for this type of application. I did look into prism but it seems over complicated and Caliburn is very easy to understand which did meet the requirements. I looked into MVVM Light but the documentation is horrible and lacks examples and I don't have time to figure it out.